# Godot magnus effect for pong clone

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm in the making of a 2d pong clone in Godot.
But I'm fairly new with Godot.
Is there a way of implementing the Magnus effect?
Like adding a fluid? or do I need to code that myself from the direction and angular velocity?
I use the PhysicsBodys of Godot. So my ball is a RidgidBody2D.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, in what way do you want to use the Magnus effect? For gameplay, or just to accentuate how it looks?

If you want to make the ball rotate as it moves, you're on the right track. [`add_torque()` and `apply_force()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_rigidbody2d.html) will rotate and move a rigibody2d respectively. It's better to use these functions rather than to try and constantly update the velocity properties, it's better for performance in Godot's default physics integration.